# Backbone: How to render template to DOM?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone and having difficulties with rendering a template.
The template itself is as unspectacular as this:

```
<script id="messageTemplate" type="text/template">
    Message: <%= content %>
</script>
```

The Backbone view & model look like this:

```
var Message = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        content: 'Default message'
    }
});

var MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'p',
    template: _.template($('#messageTemplate').html()),
    initialize: function() {
      this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
      return this;
    }
});

var msg = new Message();
var msgView = new MessageView({model: msg});
```

Nothing special I guess – just a simple model and a view using the template, replacing the placeholder with the content from `msg`.

When checking in the console with `personView.el` I get presented the correct HTML string, but how should I render it to the DOM?

Of course I already read through the Backbone and Underscore documentation, but I haven't found much regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A backbone view contains a reference to an [el](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) which may or may not be part of the page's DOM. If it isn't then you can attach it just as you would any other element.

For example

```
var msg = new Message();
var msgView = new MessageView({model: msg});
$('#someParentElement').append(msgView.el);
```

Comment: Ha, sometimes things are so painfully obvious that I can't believe it ;-)

Comment: Glad to help, it's often easy to miss the *obvious* if it hasn't been pointed out.